# How to add jQuery script to an individual page?

Tags: pages, jquery

I have this code which I want to add into a specific page of mine. I don't want to create a file for it and then include etc (though do tell if that would be the only way). Also I don't want it to be in the header as it would be included in all pages. The code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('input[name=done]:radio').click(function () {
        if ($(this).val() === "Yes") {
            $('#p-days').show();
        } else {
            $('#p-days').hide();
        }
    });
    $('input[name=already-b]:radio').click(function () {
        if ($(this).val() === "Yes") {
            $('#div-name').show();
        } else {
            $('#div-name').hide();
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

I added this in the editor by selecting the Text (not in Visual mode.) But it is not working. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Please reply as answer so that I can accept.

Comment: How do you know which page, exactly, you want to include this script on?>

Comment: you can use wordpress [is_page](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/) function

Answer (score 6):

Although @s_ha_dum is correct you *WILL* need to use jQuery no conflict within WordPress the original question is left unanswered.

> I have this code which I want to add into a specific page of mine.

There are a couple of ways to do this

### Based on Page name/slug WordPress in theme's functions.php

This method uses the WordPress hook [`wp_enqueue_scripts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts)

1. Create a new js file for your script `my-nifty-custom.js`
2. In your `functions.php` add the following

   ```
   /* Enqueue scripts (and related stylesheets) */
       add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_nifty_scripts' );
   /**
    * Registers scripts for the theme and enqueue those used site wide.
    *
    * @since 0.1.0.
    */

   function my_nifty_scripts() {
       wp_register_script('my-nifty-custom', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/my-nifty-custom.js', false, null, true);
   if(is_page('page-slug-here')){
       wp_enqueue_script('my-nifty-custom'); 
   }}
   ```

Note if you are using a child-theme or want to do it morebetter wrap the whole thing in [`after_setup_theme`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/after_setup_theme) ie:

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'nifty_theme_setup' );
function nifty_theme_setup() {
// script function and other functions that should happen after the initial theme setup
}
```

### Based on Body Class (DOM-based Routing)

This is a little bit more complicated. Luckily Paul Irish wrote a fantastic blog about it here: http://www.paulirish.com/2009/markup-based-unobtrusive-comprehensive-dom-ready-execution/

If you use this method it will get your custom JS on a per page basis based on the Body Class. For Example `<body class="nifty">`

Then you would use:

```
//clip 
 nifty : {
    init     : function(){ //custom script goes here }
  }
//clip
```

The only problem with this is the page must have the body class you are calling. For this WordPress has the function [`body_class`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class)

```
add_filter('body_class','nifty_class_names');
function nifty_class_names($classes) {
    if(is_page('page-slug-here')){
        $classes[] = 'nifty';
    }

    return $classes;
}
```

### So which method should you use?

I recommend a combination of both. Create one JavaScript file that uses Paul's method. Then use `wp_enqueue_scripts` to call that method.

### Lazy header.php method

Lastly there IS always the lazy way (which I don't recommend but am noting just for reference.

In your header.php you can do:

```
 <?php if(is_page('page-slug-here')){
           echo ('<script type="text/javascript" src="'. get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/my-nifty-custom.js"> </script>'); 
        } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

WordPress loads [jQuery in "No Conflict"](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) mode. The "$" alias doesn't work. Use the full "jQuery"-- `jQuery.$.ajax({...` or wrap your script like the example from the jQuery docs...

```
(function($) { 
  $(function() {
    // more code using $ as alias to jQuery
  });
})(jQuery);
```

There is information about this [in the Codex as well](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers).

Answer (score -1):

I've ran into this problem every time I wanted to use a jQuery plugin in my posts and pages. My solution was to create a generic jQuery plugin shortcode http://www.coding-dude.com/wp/web-design/javascript/how-to-use-jquery-plugin-with-wordpress-plugin-tutorial/

Comment: Add the crux of the answer in addition to linking to a external link.

Comment: downvoted as ianswer should be on this site, and in some unknown and unreliable third party site

Comment: Down-voted. This is not an answer to the question. Rather, it's a link to your external site, which then requires the user to subscribe to your newsletter in order to even get the plug-in you've posed as the "answer" to the question.